# Using data.table to calculate set of sums across connected paths (river network with start and end IDs for each reach)

Tags: r, sum, data.table

I've generated a data.table with >20,000,000 rows, where each row represents a pair of connected reaches in a river network. Data in each row (area, travel time, etc) are attributes of a particular "from reach" designated by REACHID. These "from reaches" are upstream of another reach of interest, designated by "ToREACHID." Below is a sample for one ToREACHID, but I actually have ~150,000 unique ToREACHID's.

```
dt = structure(list(REACHID = c(200153745L, 200153771L, 200153941L, 
200153978L), ToREACHID = c(200153771L, 200153771L, 200153771L, 
200153771L), dsREACH = c(200153771L, 200153767L, 200153771L, 
200153941L), C_HUC12 = c(70700020501, 70700020501, 70700020501, 
70700020501), W_AREA = c(1.5649, 0.0315, 0.4411, 0.366), TrW_AREA = c(1.5649, 
2.4035, 0.8071, 0.366), travel = c(0.0612471274304301, 0.00927368274189647, 
0.0373169471246884, 0.00196723306464018)), .Names = c("REACHID", 
"ToREACHID", "dsREACH", "C_HUC12", "W_AREA", "TrW_AREA", "travel"
), sorted = c("REACHID", "ToREACHID"), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))

> dt
     REACHID ToREACHID   dsREACH     C_HUC12 W_AREA TrW_AREA      travel
1: 200153745 200153771 200153771 70700020501 1.5649   1.5649 0.061247127
2: 200153771 200153771 200153767 70700020501 0.0315   2.4035 0.009273683
3: 200153941 200153771 200153771 70700020501 0.4411   0.8071 0.037316947
4: 200153978 200153771 200153941 70700020501 0.3660   0.3660 0.001967233
```

Essentially, I want to create a new variable "sumtravel" that calculates how long it takes for water to flow from the "from reach" (REACHID) to the "to reach" (ToREACHID) by summing up the individual "travel" values in between the "from" and "to" reaches, including the travel values at those reaches.  The other variable necessary to do this is dsREACH, which represents the ID of the reach immediately downstream of REACHID. I don't really need the other columns for this step, so we might be able to save some computation time using .SDcols, but I do need them for subsequent steps in my analysis.  Anyway, I think there should be some way to use dsREACH to "walk" down the river network from REACHID to its dsREACH, then to that reach's dsREACH, until REACHID==ToREACHID, adding up the "travel" values as we go.  The result would then look something like this (which I added up manually for this example):

```
> sumtravel=c(dt$travel[1]+dt$travel[2],
+                  dt$travel[2],
+                  dt$travel[3]+dt$travel[2],
+                  dt$travel[4]+dt$travel[3]+dt$travel[2])
> cbind(dt,sumtravel)
 REACHID ToREACHID   dsREACH     C_HUC12 W_AREA TrW_AREA      travel   sumtravel
1: 200153745 200153771 200153771 70700020501 1.5649   1.5649 0.061247127 0.070520810
2: 200153771 200153771 200153767 70700020501 0.0315   2.4035 0.009273683 0.009273683
3: 200153941 200153771 200153771 70700020501 0.4411   0.8071 0.037316947 0.046590630
4: 200153978 200153771 200153941 70700020501 0.3660   0.3660 0.001967233 0.048557863
```

Notice how sumtravel==travel when REACHID==ToREACHID, but is a sum of a subset of travel values for the others.

I should be able to do something like that with `while` or `repeat` to add up travel values until REACHID==ToREACHID, but I imagine `data.table` offers a more effective solution, perhaps by creating subsets of dt that include only the rows corresponding to reaches between REACHID and ToREACHID, where each REACHID in the subset is determined from the previous dsREACH. I haven't been able to figure this out, so would greatly appreciate any ideas.

P.S. This is my first submission, and I'm a data.table newbie so apologies in advance for any confusion or errors in the post or if I've missed some obvious functionality of data.table (or elsewhere in R, for that matter) that would solve this problem.

Comment: So it's really like finding a distance between points, with multiple 'waypoints'/ path to take. Easier than roads, because the networks should all converge, right (river system)? I'll have to think a bit, but in the meantime, do you think it'd be possible to start at the end, and work your way upstream rather that going downstream from all the possible starting points? If all these paths converge like I'm thinking they might, this could save some computation time. If they don't all converge, then is it at least true that water never "branches" while flowing downstream?

Comment: Also, is the problem scaling this so that it computes faster, or just how to find any way to do it?

Comment: In some sense, yes - there's really only one route from the upstream reach to the downstream one, so we don't need to calculate times for alternate routes like on roads. The networks don't quite converge - lots of rivers cross into neighboring states where my dataset cuts off, so these come up as distinct watersheds. As for whether to work up or downstream, I could do either - would just have to generate an upstream REACH field instead of downstream, but that would be pretty trivial. Given that there are many distinct watersheds, I'm not sure it's worth it, but feel free to change my mind :)

Comment: And yes it's true in this case- branched reaches have already been merged with mainstems. I'd primarily like to find a way to do it, since I haven't accomplished that yet. But when I scale up to the 20,000,000 connections, a relatively fast method might be the only option.